# Atmel Studio 7.0 update loop

Tags: microcontroller, atmel-studio, windows

Atmel Studio started asking me this morning to repair itself:

[image]

After 15 minutes, the repair is done:

[image]

Running the application, it shows again the first image:

[image]

I've done this loop three times, so far. How can I exit this loop?

I use Windows 8.1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about electrical engineering.

Comment: For what its worth, have you tried to uninstall it completely?

Comment: where would you post this kind of question? Googeling "stackexchange atmel studio" the first seven results are electronics.stackexchange[..]

Comment: The Atmel forum is the correct place.

Comment: @xaverbandi: Your question is about usage/installation of the software only, that is off-topic. Someone asking about using/understanding Atmel Studio with respect to a specific engineering problem (setting up Fuse bits for example) may be on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uninstalling and reinstalling worked.